# Overlay a image on top of a table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, cell

What I am looking to do is have a image on top of the VPS6 cell that is in blue to have a button image here is the link to the image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWN8t.jpg , I don't know how to load the image on jsfiddle.

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Package</th>
        <th>CPU / vCore </th>
        <th>Hard Disk (RAID10)</th>
        <th>Guaranteed RAM</th>
        <th>Premium Bandwidth</th>
        <th>Port Speed</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold;">
            VPS1
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; background-color:#d7f3fd">
            2.66 GHz<br>
            1 vCore
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            10GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            1 GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            500GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            100Mbps
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="table-price"><span>$9.<span>99</span></span>/month</div>
                <div class="table-button">
                    <a href="/billing/cart.php?a=add&pid=74" class="button type-3 size-2">Configure</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold; background-color:#d7f3fd">
            VPS2
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            2.66 GHz<br>
            2 vCore
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            20GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            2GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            1000GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            100Mbps
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="table-price"><span>$19.<span>99</span></span>/month</div>
                <div class="table-button">
                    <a href="/billing/cart.php?a=add&pid=75" class="button type-3 size-2">Configure</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold; background-color:#d7f3fd">
            VPS4
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            2.66 GHz</br>
            2 vCore
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            40GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            4GB
        </td >
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            1000GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            100Mbps
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="table-price"><span>$29.<span>99</span></span>/month</div>
                <div class="table-button">
                    <a href="/billing/cart.php?a=add&pid=76" class="button type-3 size-2">Configure</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold; background-color:#d7f3fd; background-image: url('bestSeller.png')">
            VPS6
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; background-color:#d7f3fd">
            2.66 GHz</br>
            4 vCore
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; background-color:#d7f3fd">
            60GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; background-color:#d7f3fd">
            6GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; background-color:#d7f3fd">
            2000GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; background-color:#d7f3fd">
            100Mbps
        </td>
        <td style=" background-color:#d7f3fd">
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="table-price"><span>$49.<span>99</span></span>/month</div>
                <div class="table-button">
                    <a href="/billing/cart.php?a=add&pid=77" class="button type-3 size-2">Configure</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold; background-color:#d7f3fd">
            VPS8
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            2.66 GHz</br>
            4 vCore
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; ">
            80GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            8GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            4000GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            100Mbps
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="table-price"><span>$59.<span>99</span></span>/month</div>
                <div class="table-button">
                    <a href="/billing/cart.php?a=add&pid=78" class="button type-3 size-2">Configure</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold; background-color:#d7f3fd">
            VPS16
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            2.66 GHz</br>
            4 vCore
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            100GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            16GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            6000GB
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            100Mbps
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="table-price"><span>$69.<span>99</span></span>/month</div>
                <div class="table-button">
                    <a href="/billing/cart.php?a=add&pid=79" class="button type-3 size-2">Configure</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[***JsFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/uyctbrz6/)

Comment: You should put your table in a simple div wrapper so it can be used as an absolute position reference for a cover over the VPS6 entry. The cover would be a div dedicated to that job. Remember how powerful a div can be. It becomes its own container for...whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely didn't see anything because your source image is huge; just setting the background image alone would have just clipped a very tiny portion of the upper right.

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold;
    background-color:#d7f3fd;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/EoDB31K.png');
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Comment: I want it for 1 cell only, the cell with VPS6

Answer (score 0):

Use an `:after` pseudo-element: https://jsfiddle.net/uyctbrz6/1/

```
#vps6:after {
  content:"";
  top:0;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/EoDB31K.png);
  background-size:100% auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

It looks pretty bad though.

Comment: it doesn't look good and I am on a 22" monitor, I can't imagine on a smaller device. I think it would look like a colored line there

Comment: Well, that was exactly what you requested though. If you wanna increase the size, it could look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/uyctbrz6/2/

Comment: I'm not the original question person. I just wanted to comment that to them even though it's what they asked for. You never know what size screen people are viewing on.